# Run macro/ VBA using Groovy Script from SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui, groovyscriptengine

I have my Soap UI execution details logged in csv file which is generated after suite execution using Grrovy script.
I have a macro/vba code which generates report based on the data in csv file. I am currently running this macro manually to generate reports.
I need to trigger the macro once execution is completed and details are logged using groovy script.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I tried to create a vbs and then tried to trigger that through Soap UI but did not worked

Comment: You have to show the code you tried in your question if you want help.

Comment: @sandeep, you have to split your question: `1/` how to run vba macro from command line, `2/` how to run command from groovy. Both answers easy to find over the internet/stackoverflow...